# How to fetch index of agent from list of agent in ANYLOGIC

Tags: simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

As i am using **getConnections()** that will Returns a **collection of agents**(*i.e,list not single agent*) connected to any agent. I want to  connect the agents (those which are present in the collection returned by  getConnections()) to another agent. Problem is **connectTo()** function is only used for connecting to particuar agent, not list of agent.

Instead of connectTo(), which function can be used or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop across all agents retrieved from `getConnections()`. A simple solution assuming you want to connect `myInitialAgent` to all agents currently connected to `myOtherAgent`:

```
for (Agent currentAgent : myOtherAgent.getConnections()) {
    myInitialAgent.connectTo(currentAgent);
}
```

You could also do it using Lambda expressions but I prefer readability ;-)